# How to fix composer problems while trying to configure magento2

Tags: magento, composer-php, magento2

I am trying to install/configure magento2. I cloned it from GitHub with:

```
cd /var/www/html
git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git
```

After that I am trying to install Composer:

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2/
composer install -v
```

And I am getting this warning.

> Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.

I tried to install phpunit but it not helped. Any idea?

Comment: And what have you tried to solve these messages? Which parts are unclear?

Comment: I have tried many things but I have no solutions. Tried to update composer but same error. Deleted it and reinstalled but doesnt metter

Comment: Have you even read the messages that you've posted? Which of these parts are unclear?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much what you can do. You get this warning because Magento uses PHPUnit 6 as dev dependency. PHP 6 EOLed in February (see [supported versions summary](https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html)) and uses deprecated package `phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects` as one of its dependencies. The right way to fix this is to upgrade PHPUnit to 7.x or 8.x line, but this rather a job for Magento devs.

As a end user who just want to use Magento, you can safely ignore this warning - it is *only* a warning to bring your attention on fact, that you're using unmaintained package. This is not a big issues, since this is only a dev dependency, and you're probably not a Magento developer. You will not get this warning if you use `--no-dev` switch (which you should use for production installation anyway):

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your message I liked your profile.